# Artifactory-migration

Tags: artifactory

I want to migrate my 20 year old maven repo to artifactory. What are my different possible options for migration starting with the easiest or the quick way to migrate and start using artifactory?

One way I could think was a remote repo in artifactory that would proxy to my existing repo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution you've already suggested (passive proxying) is seamless and useful for weeding out artifacts that are no longer needed/used, but will also take you more time to migrate away from the old instance.

For a more direct approach, Artifactory has a [repository import facility](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Importing+and+Exporting#ImportingandExporting-RepositoriesImportandExport) that allows you to import content into Artifactory from a physical location on the installed machine.

A little less convenient but also an option is to write a script that crawls the content directory  of the old repo and deploys every artifact using an HTTP PUT request.